# Ads not rendering after http to https migration

Tags: https, adsense

I found that i have a drop of 80% revenue after migration from http to https.

**Reason:**

In most of my pages ads are not getting displayed like

```
    https://www.briddles.com/riddles/math-kids
    https://www.briddles.com/riddles/weird
    https://www.briddles.com/2017/01/sachin-ramesh-tendulkar-eqaution-puzzle.html
```

Not sure why ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you redirect all of your old urls from http to https.
Google needs some time to re-index and process all your pages, before showing relevant ads. So after a week it will start to resume to previous earnings.